# Matching Location.getTime() milliseconds to NMEA sentences

Tags: android, gps, nmea, gps-time

I get GPS fix times with millisecond precision on my Nexus 7 (sometimes) as well as my Galaxy S3 (almost always). By this I mean the millis are not "000".

To make sure this was not fake time resolution introduced by the Android system, I am also capturing the NMEA sentences. And I cannot seem to find where the millis are coming from!

First, the Galaxy S3. The fix time is XX.07.55.318 (XX is hours, doesn't matter). You will see this sentence (see below for logs from both Galaxy and Nexus)

```
$GPGGA,140755.3,3920.030827,N,07721.484989,W,1,07,1.5,165.6,M,-42.0,M,,*66
```

That explains the "3xx" in the "318" millis. But what about the "x18"?

Next, the Nexus 7. The fix time is XX.16.26.508, and I cannot find where the "508" is coming from. You can trace the 1626

```
$GPRMC,141626,A,3920.038594,N,07721.487092,W,2.2,11.0,030414,8.1,W,A*2E
$GPGGA,141626,3920.038594,N,07721.487092,W,1,08,1.6,176.0,M,-42.0,M,,*7A
```

I am looking to use GPS time to achieve millisecond level time sync across distributed devices, so not knowing when the data can be trusted is troubling.

Thanks

PVS

Nexus 7 NMEA log

```
040314,10:16:22.266: NMEA:$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
040314,10:16:22.269: NMEA:$GPVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*2C
040314,10:16:22.271: NMEA:$GPRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N*53
040314,10:16:22.274: NMEA:$GPGGA,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,*66
040314,10:16:22.276: NMEA:$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
040314,10:16:22.279: NMEA:$GPVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*2C
040314,10:16:22.281: NMEA:$GPRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N*53
040314,10:16:22.284: NMEA:$GPGGA,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,*66
040314,10:16:23.274: NMEA:$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
040314,10:16:23.277: NMEA:$GPVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*2C
040314,10:16:23.281: NMEA:$GPRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N*53
040314,10:16:23.284: NMEA:$GPGGA,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,*66
040314,10:16:23.287: NMEA:$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
040314,10:16:23.292: NMEA:$GPVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*2C
040314,10:16:23.295: NMEA:$GPRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N*53
040314,10:16:23.298: NMEA:$GPGGA,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,*66
040314,10:16:23.466: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,1,18,15,26,059,33,03,00,000,,12,03,126,,14,35,253,*79
040314,10:16:23.468: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,2,18,18,77,030,,19,06,310,,21,46,191,,22,48,307,*71
040314,10:16:23.471: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,3,18,24,55,077,,27,08,278,,66,35,074,27,67,56,351,34*72
040314,10:16:23.473: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,4,18,78,11,175,,82,00,000,,77,49,133,,76,39,049,*7D
040314,10:16:23.476: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,5,18,83,21,313,,81,00,000,*70
040314,10:16:23.478: NMEA:$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
040314,10:16:23.480: NMEA:$GPVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*2C
040314,10:16:23.483: NMEA:$GPRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N*53
040314,10:16:23.485: NMEA:$GPGGA,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,*66
040314,10:16:23.488: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,1,18,15,26,059,33,03,00,000,,12,03,126,,14,35,253,*79
040314,10:16:23.508: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,2,18,18,77,030,,19,06,310,,21,46,191,,22,48,307,*71
040314,10:16:23.511: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,3,18,24,55,077,,27,08,278,,66,35,074,27,67,56,351,34*72
040314,10:16:23.513: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,4,18,78,11,175,,82,00,000,,77,49,133,,76,39,049,*7D
040314,10:16:23.516: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,5,18,83,21,313,,81,00,000,*70
040314,10:16:23.518: NMEA:$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
040314,10:16:23.521: NMEA:$GPVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*2C
040314,10:16:23.523: NMEA:$GPRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N*53
040314,10:16:23.526: NMEA:$GPGGA,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,*66
040314,10:16:23.865: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,1,18,15,26,059,38,03,00,000,,12,03,126,,14,35,253,*72
040314,10:16:23.869: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,2,18,18,77,030,,19,06,310,,21,46,191,,22,48,307,*71
040314,10:16:23.884: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,3,18,24,55,077,,27,08,278,,66,35,074,30,76,39,049,25*77
040314,10:16:23.887: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,4,18,83,21,313,30,67,56,351,36,78,11,175,,82,00,000,*7D
040314,10:16:23.890: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,5,18,77,49,133,,81,00,000,*75
040314,10:16:23.893: NMEA:$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
040314,10:16:23.895: NMEA:$GPVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*2C
040314,10:16:23.898: NMEA:$GPRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N*53
040314,10:16:23.900: NMEA:$GPGGA,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,*66
040314,10:16:23.903: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,1,18,15,26,059,38,03,00,000,,12,03,126,,14,35,253,*72
040314,10:16:23.905: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,2,18,18,77,030,,19,06,310,,21,46,191,,22,48,307,*71
040314,10:16:23.908: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,3,18,24,55,077,,27,08,278,,66,35,074,30,76,39,049,25*77
040314,10:16:23.911: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,4,18,83,21,313,30,67,56,351,36,78,11,175,,82,00,000,*7D
040314,10:16:23.913: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,5,18,77,49,133,,81,00,000,*75
040314,10:16:23.932: NMEA:$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
040314,10:16:23.935: NMEA:$GPVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*2C
040314,10:16:23.937: NMEA:$GPRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N*53
040314,10:16:23.940: NMEA:$GPGGA,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,*66
040314,10:16:24.473: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,1,18,15,26,059,38,03,00,000,,12,03,126,,14,35,253,*72
040314,10:16:24.476: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,2,18,18,77,030,,19,06,310,,21,46,191,,22,48,307,*71
040314,10:16:24.479: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,3,18,24,55,077,,27,08,278,,66,35,074,30,76,39,049,25*77
040314,10:16:24.483: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,4,18,83,21,313,30,67,56,351,36,78,11,175,,82,00,000,*7D
040314,10:16:24.485: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,5,18,77,49,133,,81,00,000,*75
040314,10:16:24.488: NMEA:$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
040314,10:16:24.491: NMEA:$GPVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*2C
040314,10:16:24.502: NMEA:$GPRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N*53
040314,10:16:24.505: NMEA:$GPGGA,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,*66
040314,10:16:24.508: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,1,18,15,26,059,38,03,00,000,,12,03,126,,14,35,253,*72
040314,10:16:24.511: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,2,18,18,77,030,,19,06,310,,21,46,191,,22,48,307,*71
040314,10:16:24.513: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,3,18,24,55,077,,27,08,278,,66,35,074,30,76,39,049,25*77
040314,10:16:24.516: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,4,18,83,21,313,30,67,56,351,36,78,11,175,,82,00,000,*7D
040314,10:16:24.518: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,5,18,77,49,133,,81,00,000,*75
040314,10:16:24.521: NMEA:$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
040314,10:16:24.523: NMEA:$GPVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*2C
040314,10:16:24.525: NMEA:$GPRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N*53
040314,10:16:24.528: NMEA:$GPGGA,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,*66
040314,10:16:25.469: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,1,18,15,26,059,39,19,06,310,23,21,46,191,25,22,48,307,32*79
040314,10:16:25.471: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,2,18,24,55,077,27,27,08,278,24,03,00,000,,12,03,126,*74
040314,10:16:25.474: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,3,18,14,35,253,,18,77,030,,66,35,074,35,76,39,049,24*78
040314,10:16:25.476: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,4,18,83,21,313,27,67,56,351,37,78,11,175,,82,00,000,*7A
040314,10:16:25.480: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,5,18,77,49,133,,81,00,000,*75
040314,10:16:25.483: NMEA:$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
040314,10:16:25.486: NMEA:$GPVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*2C
040314,10:16:25.489: NMEA:$GPRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N*53
040314,10:16:25.501: NMEA:$GPGGA,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,*66
040314,10:16:25.504: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,1,18,15,26,059,39,19,06,310,23,21,46,191,25,22,48,307,32*79
040314,10:16:25.507: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,2,18,24,55,077,27,27,08,278,24,03,00,000,,12,03,126,*74
040314,10:16:25.509: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,3,18,14,35,253,,18,77,030,,66,35,074,35,76,39,049,24*78
040314,10:16:25.512: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,4,18,83,21,313,27,67,56,351,37,78,11,175,,82,00,000,*7A
040314,10:16:25.514: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,5,18,77,49,133,,81,00,000,*75
040314,10:16:25.517: NMEA:$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
040314,10:16:25.519: NMEA:$GPVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*2C
040314,10:16:25.522: NMEA:$GPRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N*53
040314,10:16:25.540: NMEA:$GPGGA,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,*66
040314,10:16:26.481: onLocationChanged(): gps, hasAccuracy: true, Accuracy: 16.0
040314,10:16:26.540: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,1,18,14,35,253,26,15,26,059,39,18,77,030,24,19,06,310,29*7A
040314,10:16:26.543: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,2,18,21,46,191,25,22,48,307,28,24,55,077,32,27,08,278,20*7F
040314,10:16:26.545: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,3,18,03,00,000,,12,03,126,,66,35,074,37,76,39,049,26*73
040314,10:16:26.546: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,4,18,83,21,313,24,67,56,351,34,78,11,175,,82,00,000,*7A
040314,10:16:26.550: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,5,18,77,49,133,,81,00,000,*75
040314,10:16:26.552: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,1,18,14,35,253,26,15,26,059,39,18,77,030,24,19,06,310,29*7A
040314,10:16:26.554: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,2,18,21,46,191,25,22,48,307,28,24,55,077,32,27,08,278,20*7F
040314,10:16:26.555: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,3,18,03,00,000,,12,03,126,,66,35,074,37,76,39,049,26*73
040314,10:16:26.557: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,4,18,83,21,313,24,67,56,351,34,78,11,175,,82,00,000,*7A
040314,10:16:26.561: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,5,18,77,49,133,,81,00,000,*75
040314,10:16:26.563: NMEA:$GPGSA,A,3,14,15,18,19,21,22,24,27,,,,,2.9,1.6,2.4*38
040314,10:16:26.578: NMEA:$GPVTG,11.0,T,11.0,M,2.2,N,4.0,K,A*27
040314,10:16:26.580: NMEA:$GPRMC,141626,A,3920.038594,N,07721.487092,W,2.2,11.0,030414,8.1,W,A*2E
040314,10:16:26.581: NMEA:$GPGGA,141626,3920.038594,N,07721.487092,W,1,08,1.6,176.0,M,-42.0,M,,*7A
040314,10:16:26.583: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,1,18,14,35,253,26,15,26,059,39,18,77,030,24,19,06,310,29*7A
040314,10:16:26.585: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,2,18,21,46,191,25,22,48,307,28,24,55,077,32,27,08,278,20*7F
040314,10:16:26.586: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,3,18,03,00,000,,12,03,126,,66,35,074,37,76,39,049,26*73
040314,10:16:26.588: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,4,18,83,21,313,24,67,56,351,34,78,11,175,,82,00,000,*7A
040314,10:16:26.589: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,5,18,77,49,133,,81,00,000,*75
040314,10:16:26.591: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,1,18,14,35,253,26,15,26,059,39,18,77,030,24,19,06,310,29*7A
040314,10:16:26.593: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,2,18,21,46,191,25,22,48,307,28,24,55,077,32,27,08,278,20*7F
040314,10:16:26.594: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,3,18,03,00,000,,12,03,126,,66,35,074,37,76,39,049,26*73
040314,10:16:26.608: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,4,18,83,21,313,24,67,56,351,34,78,11,175,,82,00,000,*7A
040314,10:16:26.610: NMEA:$GPGSV,5,5,18,77,49,133,,81,00,000,*75
040314,10:16:26.611: NMEA:$GPGSA,A,3,14,15,18,19,21,22,24,27,,,,,2.9,1.6,2.4*38
040314,10:16:26.613: NMEA:$GPVTG,11.0,T,11.0,M,2.2,N,4.0,K,A*27
040314,10:16:26.615: NMEA:$GPRMC,141626,A,3920.038594,N,07721.487092,W,2.2,11.0,030414,8.1,W,A*2E
040314,10:16:26.616: NMEA:$GPGGA,141626,3920.038594,N,07721.487092,W,1,08,1.6,176.0,M,-42.0,M,,*7A
```

Samsung Galaxy S3 NMEA log

```
040314,10:07:16.500: NMEA:$GPGSV,3,1,10,03,01,295,,12,00,129,,14,32,250,,15,29,056,*70

040314,10:07:16.504: NMEA:$GPGSV,3,2,10,18,76,011,,19,06,313,,21,50,194,,22,45,306,*70

040314,10:07:16.508: NMEA:$GPGSV,3,3,10,24,56,084,,27,09,282,*75

040314,10:07:16.516: NMEA:$GLGSV,3,1,10,66,38,068,31,77,45,137,29,83,19,317,37,68,14,296,31*68

040314,10:07:16.519: NMEA:$GLGSV,3,2,10,78,07,175,,82,03,203,,76,41,054,,75,01,018,*69

040314,10:07:16.585: NMEA:$GLGSV,3,3,10,81,04,206,,67,54,343,*69

040314,10:07:16.588: NMEA:$GPGGA,140717.7,,,,,0,,,,,,,,*7B

040314,10:07:16.589: NMEA:$GNGNS,140717.7,,,,,NN,,,,,,*4E

040314,10:07:16.611: NMEA:$GPVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*2C

040314,10:07:16.617: NMEA:$GPRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N*53

040314,10:07:16.619: NMEA:$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E

040314,10:07:16.621: NMEA:$GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*00

040314,10:07:16.743: NMEA:$GPGSV,3,1,10,03,01,295,,12,00,129,,14,32,250,,15,29,056,*70

040314,10:07:16.747: NMEA:$GPGSV,3,2,10,18,76,011,,19,06,313,,21,50,194,,22,45,306,*70

040314,10:07:16.749: NMEA:$GPGSV,3,3,10,24,56,084,,27,09,282,*75

040314,10:07:16.751: NMEA:$GLGSV,3,1,10,66,38,068,31,77,45,137,29,83,19,317,37,68,14,296,31*68

040314,10:07:16.755: NMEA:$GLGSV,3,2,10,78,07,175,,82,03,203,,76,41,054,,75,01,018,*69

040314,10:07:16.764: NMEA:$GLGSV,3,3,10,81,04,206,,67,54,343,*69

040314,10:07:16.784: NMEA:$GPGGA,140718.5,,,,,0,,,,,,,,*76

040314,10:07:16.786: NMEA:$GNGNS,140718.5,,,,,NN,,,,,,*43

040314,10:07:16.788: NMEA:$GPVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*2C

040314,10:07:16.803: NMEA:$GPRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N*53

040314,10:07:16.805: NMEA:$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E

040314,10:07:16.815: NMEA:$GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*00

040314,10:07:17.771: NMEA:$GPGSV,3,1,10,14,32,250,29,15,29,056,34,19,06,313,38,24,56,084,26*70

040314,10:07:17.776: NMEA:$GPGSV,3,2,10,03,01,295,,12,00,129,,18,76,011,,21,50,194,*7E

040314,10:07:17.778: NMEA:$GPGSV,3,3,10,22,45,306,,27,09,282,*78

040314,10:07:17.782: NMEA:$GLGSV,3,1,10,66,38,068,30,77,45,137,31,76,41,054,30,83,19,317,38*6D

040314,10:07:17.784: NMEA:$GLGSV,3,2,10,68,14,296,36,78,07,175,,82,03,203,,75,01,018,*6F

040314,10:07:17.787: NMEA:$GLGSV,3,3,10,81,04,206,,67,54,343,*69

040314,10:07:17.790: NMEA:$GPGGA,140719.5,3920.022524,N,07721.493920,W,1,03,3.2,153.4,M,-42.0,M,,*66

040314,10:07:17.792: NMEA:$GNGNS,140719.5,3920.022524,N,07721.493920,W,AA,08,3.2,153.4,-42.0,,*59

040314,10:07:17.794: NMEA:$GPVTG,36.8,T,36.8,M,2.0,N,3.6,K,A*24

040314,10:07:17.797: NMEA:$GPRMC,140719.5,A,3920.022524,N,07721.493920,W,2.0,36.8,030414,,,A*43

040314,10:07:17.800: NMEA:$GPGSA,A,2,14,15,19,,,,,,,,,,3.3,3.2,1.0*3A

040314,10:07:17.803: NMEA:$GNGSA,A,2,14,15,19,,,,,,,,,,3.3,3.2,1.0*24

040314,10:07:17.807: NMEA:$GNGSA,A,2,66,77,76,83,68,,,,,,,,3.3,3.2,1.0*29

040314,10:07:17.843: onLocationChanged(): gps, hasAccuracy: true, Accuracy: 40.0
040314,10:07:18.771: NMEA:$GPGSV,3,1,10,14,32,250,31,15,29,056,31,18,76,011,30,19,06,313,37*75

040314,10:07:18.774: NMEA:$GPGSV,3,2,10,22,45,306,37,24,56,084,27,27,09,282,31,03,01,295,*7F

040314,10:07:18.776: NMEA:$GPGSV,3,3,10,12,00,129,,21,50,194,*7B

040314,10:07:18.778: NMEA:$GLGSV,3,1,10,66,38,068,27,77,45,137,23,76,41,054,26,83,19,317,37*60

040314,10:07:18.780: NMEA:$GLGSV,3,2,10,67,54,343,31,68,14,296,37,78,07,175,,82,03,203,*62

040314,10:07:18.784: NMEA:$GLGSV,3,3,10,75,01,018,,81,04,206,*67

040314,10:07:18.786: NMEA:$GPGGA,140720.5,3920.035586,N,07721.476384,W,1,07,1.4,143.5,M,-42.0,M,,*6D

040314,10:07:18.788: NMEA:$GNGNS,140720.5,3920.035586,N,07721.476384,W,AA,13,1.4,143.5,-42.0,,*5C

040314,10:07:18.798: NMEA:$GPVTG,36.8,T,36.8,M,0.5,N,0.9,K,A*2F

040314,10:07:18.801: NMEA:$GPRMC,140720.5,A,3920.035586,N,07721.476384,W,0.5,36.8,030414,,,A*4F

040314,10:07:18.805: NMEA:$GPGSA,A,3,14,15,18,19,22,24,27,,,,,,2.3,1.4,1.7*33

040314,10:07:18.815: NMEA:$GNGSA,A,3,14,15,18,19,22,24,27,,,,,,2.3,1.4,1.7*2D

040314,10:07:18.818: NMEA:$GNGSA,A,3,66,77,76,83,67,68,,,,,,,2.3,1.4,1.7*2B

040314,10:07:18.822: onLocationChanged(): gps, hasAccuracy: true, Accuracy: 22.0
040314,10:07:19.744: NMEA:$GPGSV,3,1,10,14,32,250,30,15,29,056,31,18,76,011,32,19,06,313,37*76

040314,10:07:19.748: NMEA:$GPGSV,3,2,10,22,45,306,40,24,56,084,25,27,09,282,34,03,01,295,*78

040314,10:07:19.752: NMEA:$GPGSV,3,3,10,12,00,129,,21,50,194,*7B

040314,10:07:19.757: NMEA:$GLGSV,3,1,10,66,38,068,29,77,45,137,24,76,41,054,24,83,19,317,39*65

040314,10:07:19.817: NMEA:$GLGSV,3,2,10,67,54,343,34,68,14,296,37,78,07,175,,82,03,203,*67

040314,10:07:19.820: NMEA:$GLGSV,3,3,10,75,01,018,,81,04,206,*67

040314,10:07:19.822: NMEA:$GPGGA,140721.5,3920.034010,N,07721.480904,W,1,07,1.4,153.5,M,-42.0,M,,*6D

040314,10:07:19.835: NMEA:$GNGNS,140721.5,3920.034010,N,07721.480904,W,AA,13,1.4,153.5,-42.0,,*5C

040314,10:07:19.837: NMEA:$GPVTG,36.8,T,36.8,M,0.0,N,0.0,K,A*23

040314,10:07:19.842: NMEA:$GPRMC,140721.5,A,3920.034010,N,07721.480904,W,0.0,36.8,030414,,,A*4B

040314,10:07:19.844: NMEA:$GPGSA,A,3,14,15,18,19,22,24,27,,,,,,2.3,1.4,1.7*33

040314,10:07:19.847: NMEA:$GNGSA,A,3,14,15,18,19,22,24,27,,,,,,2.3,1.4,1.7*2D

040314,10:07:19.849: NMEA:$GNGSA,A,3,66,77,76,83,67,68,,,,,,,2.3,1.4,1.7*2B

040314,10:07:19.872: onLocationChanged(): gps, hasAccuracy: true, Accuracy: 15.0
040314,10:07:53.745: NMEA:$GPGSV,3,1,10,22,45,306,34,03,01,295,,12,00,129,,14,32,250,*7F

040314,10:07:53.749: NMEA:$GPGSV,3,2,10,15,29,057,,18,76,012,,19,06,313,,21,50,192,*7C

040314,10:07:53.754: NMEA:$GPGSV,3,3,10,24,56,084,,27,09,282,*75

040314,10:07:53.766: NMEA:$GLGSV,3,1,10,77,45,136,27,67,54,343,28,78,07,175,,82,03,203,*6B

040314,10:07:53.770: NMEA:$GLGSV,3,2,10,66,38,068,,76,41,054,,75,01,018,,83,19,317,*69

040314,10:07:53.831: NMEA:$GLGSV,3,3,10,81,04,206,,68,14,296,*6B

040314,10:07:53.837: NMEA:$GPGGA,140755.5,,,,,0,,,,,,,,*7F

040314,10:07:53.842: NMEA:$GNGNS,140755.5,,,,,NN,,,,,,*4A

040314,10:07:53.847: NMEA:$GPVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*2C

040314,10:07:53.852: NMEA:$GPRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N*53

040314,10:07:53.856: NMEA:$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E

040314,10:07:53.861: NMEA:$GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*00

040314,10:07:54.006: NMEA:$GPGSV,3,1,10,14,32,250,26,15,29,057,26,18,76,012,26,19,06,313,32*75

040314,10:07:54.010: NMEA:$GPGSV,3,2,10,22,45,306,34,24,56,084,24,27,09,282,30,03,01,295,*7E

040314,10:07:54.013: NMEA:$GPGSV,3,3,10,12,00,129,,21,50,192,*7D

040314,10:07:54.016: NMEA:$GLGSV,3,1,10,77,45,136,27,83,19,317,33,67,54,343,28,68,14,296,30*6B

040314,10:07:54.018: NMEA:$GLGSV,3,2,10,78,07,175,,82,03,203,,66,38,068,,76,41,054,*66

040314,10:07:54.021: NMEA:$GLGSV,3,3,10,75,01,018,,81,04,206,*67

040314,10:07:54.065: NMEA:$GPGGA,140755.3,3920.030827,N,07721.484989,W,1,07,1.5,165.6,M,-42.0,M,,*66

040314,10:07:54.067: NMEA:$GNGNS,140755.3,3920.030827,N,07721.484989,W,AA,11,1.5,165.6,-42.0,,*55

040314,10:07:54.069: NMEA:$GPVTG,294.4,T,294.4,M,2.4,N,4.5,K,A*24

040314,10:07:54.071: NMEA:$GPRMC,140755.3,A,3920.030827,N,07721.484989,W,2.4,294.4,030414,,,A*77

040314,10:07:54.074: NMEA:$GPGSA,A,3,14,15,18,19,22,24,27,,,,,,2.3,1.5,1.8*3D

040314,10:07:54.076: NMEA:$GNGSA,A,3,14,15,18,19,22,24,27,,,,,,2.3,1.5,1.8*23

040314,10:07:54.077: NMEA:$GNGSA,A,3,77,83,67,68,,,,,,,,,2.3,1.5,1.8*24

040314,10:07:54.079: onLocationChanged(): gps, hasAccuracy: true, Accuracy: 12.0
```

Comment: You may want to examine the implementation of the Android API you are using and see where it gets its data.  If this call is accurate sometime *after* the last GPS fix, then likely what you are reading is some on-device clock disciplined by the GPS (or perhaps **not** by the GPS but by something else such as the mobile carrier's sense of time).  I'd be hesitant to expect success in synchronizing devices too closely, especially across manufacturers and versions.  You also have to consider that there's not much which Android devices do in the way of I/O which is this realtime.