# How to prevent the user selecting past date in Android date picker

Tags: android, android-calendar, android-datepicker

Hi i am making an Appointment app i am using **firebase database** as my backend.

I want to restrict the user selecting the previous dates. I got the solution 
[from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23762231/how-to-disable-past-dates-in-android-date-picker)

But I **don't know where to put the code to get it work**. I am putting my code below please guide me for the same...

Another question is, if the user **changes the system date and time** the **date in datepicker also changes** is there any way that i can restrict user to select the current date or tomorrow's date only but not the yesterdays date.

*for ex. taking ServerValue.TIMESTAMP and converting this into date and then comparing the selected date and date got from TIMESTAMP.*

**Appointment.java**

```
/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Appointment extends Fragment {

    @BindView(R.id.apointFirstName)
    EditText apointFirstName;
    @BindView(R.id.apointLastName)
    EditText apointLastName;
    @BindView(R.id.apointPhoneNumber)
    EditText apointPhoneNumber;
    @BindView(R.id.apointEmail)
    EditText apointEmail;
    @BindView(R.id.apointDate)
    EditText apointDate;
    @BindView(R.id.availTimeSpinner)
    Spinner availTimeSpinner;
    @BindView(R.id.bookAppointmentButton)
    Button book_btn;
    @BindView(R.id.cancelAppointmentButton)
    Button cancel_btn;

    Calendar mCal;
    int day, month, year;
    String mCurrentDate;
    String fname,lname,email;
    int phone;
    String timestamp = String.valueOf(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

    public Appointment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_appointment, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this,view);


        setCurrentDate();

        apointDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectDate();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    // set the current date on the text view
    private void setCurrentDate() {

        mCal = Calendar.getInstance();

        day = mCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        month = mCal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        year = mCal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        month = month +1;

        mCurrentDate = (day+"/"+month+"/"+year);

    }

    //open the datepickerdialogue
    private void selectDate() {
        if(getActivity()!=null) {
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    month = month + 1;
                    apointDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + year);
                }
            }, year, month, day);


            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

add below line user can not select old data..

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **`datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);`** to disable paste date in date picker

Try this

```
private void selectDate() {
        if(getActivity()!=null) {
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    month = month + 1;
                    apointDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + year);
                }
            }, year, month, day);

            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    }
```

> the user changes the system date and time the date in datepicker also changes is there any way that i can restrict user to select the current date or tomorrow's

Check this link

1. [Get Real Time - Not Device Set Time in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15808333/get-real-time-not-device-set-time-in-android)
2. [Android - Get current time without dependency on device's clock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26969288/android-get-current-time-without-dependency-on-devices-clock)
3. [How to get device independent local date and time Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283040/how-to-get-device-independent-local-date-and-time-android)

Comment: @Aakash check this it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26969288/android-get-current-time-without-dependency-on-devices-clock